# Manually recalculate 'computed properties'

Tags: polymer, computed-properties

If I have a custom element

```
Polymer({
  name: 'dane',

  computed: {
    message: 'greet(name)'
  },

  greet: function(name) {
    return 'hello ' + name + Date.now();
  }
})
```

When I change `name` polymer will automatically recompute `message`, but is there a way to recompute `message` without changing `name`?

Answer (score 4):

You could add another input value to the compute expression, i.e.:

```
message: 'greet(name,x)'
```

and then force a re-compute by updating x.

Keep in mind computed properties are read-only so you can't directly assign it a value.

Comment: Clever hack. I hope there's a better way but this might work out! Also you're right to point out that you can't assign a value.